# Excel How to split a string at the last space before line length

Tags: excel, string, split

I'm trying to get a text string into SQL. In the db, I have Description 1 and Description 2 fields. Description 1 length is 100 chars, and Description 2 is 50 chars.

How do I split a line in Excel to find the last space before a character limit (eg. I want to split the line at the first space before character 100 - I don't want to split in the middle of a word).

Seems this might be a common task, but I can't find anything yet.

Comment: check out the =find function 
FIND(find_text, within_text, [start_num])

Comment: Use left(A1,100) and right(A1,50) unless your space is not at position 101…

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,FIND("}_}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}_}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)` AND `=MID(A1,FIND("}_}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}_}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))+1,50`